# Android Development - Thread And Handler together issue

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, handle

So what I'm trying to do is basically when/as the user is typing inside a EditText, I basically want to search for all the words that start with whatever is inside the EditText (achieved by doing editText.getText().toString()). I added a TextChangedListener to my EditText and whenever the user types any character, it calls the method called "addResults" which uses the following code:

```
public void addResults(final String prefix){
    if(thread != null){
        try{
        thread.wait();
        thread.interrupt();
        thread.suspend();
        thread.destroy();
        thread.stop();
        thread = null;
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
    results.clear();
    resultsArray = null;
    this.prefix = prefix;
    thread = new Thread(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        URL url = new URL(String.format(WORD_URL, prefix));
                        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                        connection.setReadTimeout(Timeout.TIMEOUT);
                        connection.setConnectTimeout(Timeout.TIMEOUT);
                        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                        Scanner reader = new Scanner(is);
                        while(reader.hasNextLine()){
                            String line = reader.nextLine();
                            if(line != null){
                                if(line.contains(String.format(CHECKER, prefix))){
                                    String[] s = line.split(String.format(CHECKER, prefix));
                                    String[] s2 = s[1].split(INIT_SPLIT);
                                    if(s2.length > 0){
                                        for(int i = 1; i < s2.length; i++){
                                            String l = s2[i];
                                            String[] split = l.split(SECOND_SPLIT);
                                            results.add(new Result(prefix, split[0].trim()));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        resultsArray = WordSearcher.toArray(results);
                        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                        reader.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
    thread.start();
}
```

And there is nothing wrong with that method, it does indeed get the correct words and everything but the problem is is that if the user types WHILE its trying to get the words, it doesn't seem to update (still displays results from old search). Inside my Handler, I am basically just setting the adapter of my ListView to the string array (resultsArray) produced from the method). And some possible solutions that I can think of is either immediately stop the thread's execution, or find a way to make it cancel the previous request if the user is typing while the thread is running and make it process the current text inside the EditText. Any other solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Note: It works fine if the thread finishes executing before the user types. It only becomes a issue when the thread is still executing and the user begins to type.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, Your code under `try` works not as You expect it to. I believe, it actually doesn't stop previous thread (refer to **deprecated** methods documentation [suspend()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend%28%29), [destroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#destroy%28%29), [stop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28java.lang.Throwable%29) ).
Looks like You might have number of simultaneously running threads and receiving only single message.
I would suggest to check [isInterrupted()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) inside Your runnable in while loop (like Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) and don't send a message if thread has been interrupted.

Comment: Alright I added the code inside my Thread and I'll see if it works. Thanks.

Edit: It doesn't seem to work

Comment: When I did research before asking this question, apparently it's a good thing to use a Timer and TimerTask, maybe I should look in to that. Although I don't really understand the proper usage, so if anyone can guide me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have You logged and ensured that only single thread is running at during typing? Another suggestion is to add some timeout for typing (simplest way - use handler and postDelayed() to not handle every letter if user is typing fast, but wait for some seconds of inactivity).

Comment: I don't really understand due to my lack of knowledge in Android Development. If you could please redirect me to a site that would show an example, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found any appropriate example. Generally, just move addResults() call to some runnable and call postDelayed() instead of direct call to addResults() from TextEntry callback.